# turning off caching on specific blocks

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, redis, block-cache

I'm working with emarsys and i keep having issues with their webextend scripts. Data is being served to wrong customers and abandoned emails are populating the wrong items. They keep telling me it's because caching needs to be turned off on their blocks. So I've implemented this below and it should work fine but i'm still running into issues.

```
    <reference name="before_body_end"> 
        <block type="core/template" name="emarsys_webextend_script" as="emarsys_webextend_script" template="tm/emarsys/webextend.phtml"> 
            <action method="setCacheLifetime" /> <!-- disable caching -->
            <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
            <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Could this have anything to do with redis?